# don't forwards spam mails with spamassassin

Tags: postfix, spamassassin

I have a mail server running `postfix` for my youth movement. I use the mailserver to create groups that everyone can mail to so the right persons receive this mail. It's a relay server.

I noticed that a lot of spam had been send to this server and this made the server listed in different blacklists. I have now installed `spamassassin` to stop the spam, but now spamassassins sends the mails throught with a modified subject.

Is there a way to not send these mails to the user, but keep a log on the server so I can see when a mail has beet wrongfully marked as spam?

Comment: Do you mean something like spam quarantine? Instead alters subject, you want spamassasin put it in quarantine vault?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am looking for. I have found some ways to do this [here](https://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/SpamQuarantine), but both projects are no longer maintained. Is there any newer add-on?

Answer (score 3):

Spamassasin primary purpose is classifying email (spam or not). To handle quarantine vault, you can use additional package such as [amavis](http://www.amavis.org/), [maia](http://www.maiamailguard.com/maia/wiki) or [SAQ](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saq/).

For more info, please check [official documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/spamassassin/SpamQuarantine)

Comment: I have installed `amavis` and included it in `postfix`. But I still get mails from spamassassin where it says spam has been detected

Comment: amavis had several configuration to quarantine spam or not based on spam score. More info http://www200.pair.com/mecham/spam/amavisd-settings.html

Comment: But where do I put these settings. I can't seem to find a config file for amavis.

Comment: depending your OS. Likely in `/etc/amavisd.conf`

Comment: I am using `ubuntu server 12.04`. I have one folder, `/etc/amavis` and the only content in this folder is `conf.d  en_US  README.l10n`. Should I create the config myself?

Comment: First, figure how to integrate amavisd, postfix and spamassasin together on Ubuntu (a bit complicated but many tutorials from google result). After that, you can adjust amavis configuration as you need